Bun: streaming stdout of spawned subprocess to Response without copying
In my Bun backend, am calling a subprocess which returns a (large) json text on its stdout. This should, without changes, returned in the Response.
I am doing it like this:
const tsv2json = Bun.spawn('tsv2json', filename])
const content = await Bun.readableStreamToText(tsv2json.stdout);
return new Response(content, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });

This works, but I think there is unnecessary copying of large strings going on.
I would like it to work like this:
return new Response(tsv2json.stdout, { headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });

But it does not work; the Response is returned but with no content and subprocess seems to hang.
What am I missing?
